# Tracking FileStream data with Change Data Capture

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, change-data-capture, sqlfilestream

I need a database that

- manages documents with transaction support and
- can restore the state of a row and the corresponding document to an earlier point in time.

I am leaning towards using the SQL Server FileStream feature because it seems to fit most of my requirements perfectly.

For data history the SQL Server solution seems to be the Change Data Capture (CDC) feature.

1. Does this work in combination with FileStream on SQL Server 2012? Do document changes made via the Win32 SqlFileStream class get tracked? Can I restore older states of my documents in this way?
2. If not, what would be the recommended solution for tracking the document changes together with the metadata that is being stored in the corresponding column? Triggers?